msal loginPopup from outlook web plugin
I'm developing an Outlook plugin. From the plugin, I need to authenticate my app to access users' emails and attachments, but I'm having trouble with that. Here's what I've tried so far.
const msalConfig = {
  auth: {
    clientId: MSAL_CLIENT_ID,
    authority: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common`,
    //redirectUri: MSAL_REDIRECT_URI,
  },
};

  const handleConnect = async () => {
    const msalInstance = await PublicClientApplication.createPublicClientApplication(msalConfig);
    try {
      const loginRequest = {
        scopes: ["profile", "openid", "User.Read", "Mail.ReadWrite", "MailboxSettings.ReadWrite"],
      };
      const loginResponse = await msalInstance.loginPopup(loginRequest);
         console.log("Logged in successfully:", loginResponse);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Login failed:", error);
    }
  };

By idea I have to receive a loginResponse here. But I have this error message
AADSTS500113: No reply address is registered for the application.

So I went to my app and tried to register a ngrok url. https://bc1876f54383.ngrok.app. I exposed the localhost of the plugin and I see the url is used in ngrok console. But ngrok reported
ERR_NGROK_3004
ngrok gateway error
The server returned an invalid or incomplete HTTP response.

Anyone willing to help me with this mess? Is this right approach or I have to redirect to my backend server and than pool the access token from it.

What is the Front-end technology you are using? What is the Azure authentication platform you have configured in Azure AD?
